# Core ML Vision producing incorrect answers

Tags: ios, xcode, coreml

I'm using Apple's Core ML to visually recognize items in an image but it's returning incorrect answers sometimes identifying shoes as a knife etc. Is there a way to provide feedback about CoreML and hopefully guide it towards correctly identifying the items in an image?

Comment: What model are you using? Have you checked whether the images you are passing to the model are correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably giving the Core ML model inputs that it does not expect. I wrote a blog post about the most common mistakes: http://machinethink.net/blog/help-core-ml-gives-wrong-output/

Answer (score 0):

I would open a feedback ticket at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ 
Apple is really glad to get devs feedback. Try to detail yours as deeply as possible :)

EDIT : I would also suggest that you try another CoreML model ! I had a few tries with Inception V3 which worked like a charm with my apps. https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/

Comment: so it's a bug? I'd need this to be up and running within 4-6 weeks, can't afford to be waiting years for updates unfortunately!

Comment: @C13 Only they will be able to confirm wether if it's a bug or not. They reply pretty fast to feedbacks. I'll update my answer with another suggestion aswell

Comment: @C13 - This isn't a bug, Core ML is most likely working as it should. What results you're getting comes down to what model you're using, what it was trained to detect, how it was trained, and how you're feeding images or video into it. If you're using a pretrained model trained against ImageNet (the most likely case, since it doesn't seem like you have trained your own), you'll have to examine the categories it was trained to detect. For example, the dataset only contains running shoes and may not pick up loafers. For best results, you'll want to train your own network on your own dataset.

Comment: @BradLarson Sorry for delayed response. You're dead right - I hadn't realized there was a training element. I'll have to research how to do this and hopefully get the results I'd like! Thank you!